# issue where In SAS Deployment wizard SAS ODBC Driver for Web infrastructure platform Data Server is not downloaded

Tags: sas, odbc

What if while installing SAS, I face issue where In SAS Deployment wizard SAS ODBC Driver for Web infrastructure platform Data Server is not downloaded , it is showing completed with error. What would happen if SAS Deployment wizard SAS ODBC Driver for Web infrastructure platform Data Server is showing this error. Can we code/program without the need of this fucntionality?

Answer (score 0):

You are best contacting SAS support for a specific question like this - it is not a programming question, but rather a SAS administrator question.